# expand div with display:flex

Tags: html, css

I am trying to animate the expansion of a div with flexible height. The animation is going from height: 0px to the target height. However, I do not no the target height. Therefore I have just assumed a height which is near the real height. This gives a very bad looking effect, since I am always overestimating or underestimating the height.

```css
.expandable {
  background-color: red;
  width: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: hidden;
  animation-name: expand;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-out;
}
@keyframes expand {
  from {
    height: 0px
  }
  to {
    height: 100px
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="expandable">
  text
  <br />text
  <br/>text
  <br />text
  <br/>text
  <br />text
  <br/>text
</div>
```

See my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gh3y1sbf/

what I would like to see is that the animation is smooth to the actual target height of the div.

Any ideas how this is possible? preferably without using javascript. Also, I am not using JQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this :

[How can I transition height: 0; to height: auto; using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508605/how-can-i-transition-height-0-to-height-auto-using-css)

Animate max-height rather than height !

Comment: Be cautious thought. Using max-height can cause the a strange delay when you have a small menu with a large max-height value

Comment: And in order to animate "height", javascript is required, right ?

Comment: hmm, I got this working, however i would have to set the max-height to something higher than the actual height. so preferably to something really high. But I think this should be working fine. Thank you!

Comment: Yes. CSS3 still cannot achieve animation to *some auto height* - without strange delays and stuff.